# Saving one Rails form to multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem understanding how to save a model that spans two tables. The JSON object for the item I'm trying to save looks like this:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "hardware_id": 3,
    "ip_address": 10.5.2.68,
    "name": "test device",
    "release": "v0.2.3",
    "properties": {
      "hardware_id": 3,
      "password": null,
      "wifi_visit_threshold_autocal": -100,
      "last_wifi_autocal_date": 1,
      "visit_threshold": -50,
      "inner_threshold": -30
    }
  }
}
```

And my model is as follows:

```
class Hardware
  include JSONClient::Model
  include TimestampAccessor

....

attributes do
  scalar :hardware_id, :ip_address, :name, :release
end
```

The problem I'm facing is that the hardware fields are in one table, and the properties are located in another for reasons beyond my control.

To be able to save the hardware attributes and properties from the same form, would I need to create another JSONClient model for the properties and define a one to one relation between the hardware model and the hardware properties model?

I've read in other posts that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` may be the answer I am looking for, but I am so new to Rails that I'm getting pretty lost about how to create a form that does anything more than save fields that are all in the same model.

Thank you so much in advance for any help you cah offer.

Comment: Yes, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is the way to go. I've just googled a bit and found this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/ might be good for u

Comment: Can I strongly recommend reading all the Rails Guides? but the one you want specifically for this is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html